# Nifi - Remove zeros(00) of my json in Nifi

Tags: json, text, apache-nifi, jolt

Good Night.

I need to remove the zeros of "numero":

```
{
  "cnpjemitente" : "48791685000168",
  "numero" : "001262851",
  "chavenfe" : "35221148791685000168550030012628511100259840",
  "serie" : "3  "
}
```

The correct column:

```
{
  "cnpjemitente" : "48791685000168",
  "numero" : "1262851",
  "chavenfe" : "35221148791685000168550030012628511100259840",
  "serie" : "3  "
}
```

I need the leading zeros to be removed whenever possible.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can consecutively use the following within a ***JoltTransformJSON*** processor ;

- **`toInteger`** and **`toString`** functions in a **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation spec
- and then **remove** transformation in order to get rid of the auxiliary attribute `"numero_"`

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "numero_": "=toInteger(@(1,numero))",// converts to 1262851(leading zeroes removed)
      "numero": "=toString(@(1,numero_))"// converts to "1262851"(quoted)
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "numero_": ""
    }
  }
]
```

or use

- **`toInteger`** and **`toString`** functions in each individual consecutive **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation spec

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "numero": "=toInteger"// converts to 1262851
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "numero": "=toString"// converts to "1262851"
    }
  }
]
```